# JSONException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement, different environtment

Tags: java, exception

Hello below I share my code:
The problem is it is working without any error, but I get "exception JsonException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement" in the server.

The problem is solved when I add declaration of "throws JSONException" in the following two methods, but actually I do not want to do that. What could be the reason for that?

```
private JSONArray convertStringToJsonArray(String source)throws JSONException {
    return new JSONArray(source);
}

private JSONObject getElementIndexAt(JSONArray jsonArray, int index)throws JSONException {
    return jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
}
```

---

```
public class JsonModifier {

public String getElementIndexAt(String source, int index){
    String output;

    try
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = convertStringToJsonArray(source);
        JSONObject jsonObject = getElementIndexAt(jsonArray, index);
        output = convertJsonToString(jsonObject);
    }
    catch(JSONException ex)
    {
        log.error("Page not found, exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        output = "Page not found, exception: " + ex.getMessage();
    }

    return output;
}

private JSONArray convertStringToJsonArray(String source) {
    return new JSONArray(source);
}

private JSONObject getElementIndexAt(JSONArray jsonArray, int index) {
    return jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
}

private String convertJsonToString(JSONObject jsonObject){
    return jsonObject.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html#getJsonObject-int-), getJSONObject and the constructor throw Exception. So, if you don't surround those functions with try/catch, you must throw that exception upwards.

Note: you are using try/catch in your own functions, thats why your solution works.

Hope this helps :)